# How to get a wordpress page appeared in google search

Tags: wordpress, seo

I have added a new page in wordpress site and want that to be shown in google search results. How can I achieve this ??

Thanks for the help in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XML sitemap](http://sitemap.org)

The other step is [Html Sitemap](http://www.ehow.com/sitemap-1112170.html).

You can use [Google Webmaster Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) to submit XML Sitemap.